# do-while input validation within array for loop

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, scanf, do-while

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to ask the user to input 5 Blood Pressure readings within a certain range (>= 40 and <= 100). I'm trying to create an input validation using a `do`-`while` loop within the `for` loop that scans those inputs to an array.

While I am getting an error message that the input is out of range and being asked to input again, The value I entered previously is still being added to the sum.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about fixing this so I would really appreciate some insight.

I've tried moving the scan to after the `if` conditional but that just caused the `do`-`while` loop to break and go on infinitely. I've also tried changing the `if` into another `while` loop but the same thing happened (might have just done it incorrectly).

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    do {
        //input for 5 diastolic BP readings
        printf("Enter the Diastolic (bottom) part of your 5 blood pressure tests in the range 40-100 (in mmHg): \n");
        scanf("%f", &dia[i]);

        if (dia[i] < 40 || dia[i] > 100) {
            printf("Error, Please input your Diastolic blood pressure within the range 40-100. \n");
        }

        sumDia += dia[i];
    } while (dia[i] < 40 || dia[i] > 100);
}
```

Comment: You could use `continue` after the `printf` call. It will jump to the end of the loop.

Comment: You could also move `sumDia += dia[i];` outside the `do while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just move this statement

```
 sumDia += dia[i];
```

below the do-while loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    do{
      //input for 5 diastolic BP readings
      printf("Enter the Diastolic (bottom) part of your 5 blood pressure tests in the range 40-100 (in mmHg): \n");
      scanf("%f", &dia[i]);

      if(dia[i] < 40 || dia[i] > 100)
      {
         printf("Error, Please input your Diastolic blood pressure within the range 40-100. \n");
      }
    }while(dia[i] < 40 || dia[i] > 100);

    sumDia += dia[i];
}
```

Pay attention to that you should also check whether the user entered a number instead for example a non-digit symbol. For example

```
    do {
        //input for 5 diastolic BP readings
        printf( "Enter the Diastolic (bottom) part of your 5 blood pressure tests in the range 40-100 (in mmHg): \n" );
        int result = scanf( "%f", &dia[i] );

        if ( result != 1 || dia[i] < 40.0f || dia[i] > 100.0f )
        {
            printf( "Error, Please input your Diastolic blood pressure within the range 40-100. \n" );
            if (result != 1)
            {
                while( getchar() != '\n' );
                dia[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    } while ( dia[i] < 40.0f || dia[i] > 100.0f);

    sumDia += dia[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so much code!

```
// input 5 diastolic BP readings
i = 0;
while( i < 5 ) {
    puts( "Enter the Diastolic (bottom) part of your 5 blood pressure tests in the range 40-100 (in mmHg):" );

    if( scanf( " %f", &dia[i] ) != 1 || dia[i] < 40 || dia[i] > 100 )
        puts("Error, Please input your Diastolic blood pressure within the range 40-100." );
    else
        sumDia += dia[ i++ ]; // accepted and moving on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input
- you should read and discard invalid input, in case it could not be parsed as  a number
- you should test for `EOF` and stop reading
- you should use a `continue` statement or an `else` clause to avoid adding the invalid reading.

Here is a modified version:

```
    // input for 5 diastolic BP readings
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (;;) {
            double value;

            printf("Enter the Diastolic (bottom) part of your 5 blood pressure tests in the range 40-100 (in mmHg): \n");
            if (scanf("%f", &value) == 1 && value >= 40 && value <= 100) {
                dia[i] = value;
                break;
            }
            // read and discard the rest of the input line
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
            printf("Error, Please input your Diastolic blood pressure within the range 40-100. \n");
        }
        if (c == EOF) {
            printf("end of file reached\n");
            break;
        }
        sumDia += dia[i];
    }
}
```